# Length of a vector arrow

Tags: qgis

What is the unit of length of a vector arrow scaled by a specific scale in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Is that a line layer? What QGIS version do you have?

Comment: Actually it's a raster data and my QGIS version is 3.26.3

Answer (score 0):

A scale factor should be dimensionless, i.e. a line with a length of 1m and 100px scaled 10x should be 10m and 1000px respectively.

The resulting value should still be in the original unit.

Comment: Sure but as the dialog doesn't let you specify a length or unit for the arrow how do you know what you scale ?

Comment: @J.R check https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/32c2cea54cb92bbb2243b222816c8154c2b9adf9/src/core/mesh/qgsmeshvectorrenderer.cpp#L177-L183 and the relevant comment `Algorithm how to transform vector magnitude to length of arrow on the device in pixels` from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/99a832ef1e2103a13a48e43ca7dd1e41d32c3902/src/core/mesh/qgsmeshrenderersettings.h#L209